# Ajax request not passing parameter to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tried looking in stackoverflow because this looked so trivial. Found many similar questions and read through them. Found no solution using these examples. Here is my code, can anyone help?

```
function testAjax() {
return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("Nodes","Competence", new { userId = Sven });',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
}

var promise = testAjax();

promise.success(function (data) {
   var dataConverted = JSON.stringify(data);
   $('#tree').treeview({ data: dataConverted, multiSelect: true });
});
```

ASP.NET MVC method

```
public JsonResult Nodes(string userId)
    {
        var temp = userId;
        var list = new List<Node>();
        list.Add(new Node("Test1"));
        list.Add(new Node("Test2"));
        list.Add(new Node("Test3"));

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

EDIT:
Just before I was about to turn crazy on Halloween night, i figured out to try in a new session. Turns out it was just a caching problem..Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: just wonder have you debugged, and controller function is reachable?

Comment: What error message have you gotten???

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine. I just copied and pasted it to a local project and it worked fine (userId param had the value you sent "Test")

Comment: @M.A.Cordeiro if it's a binding issue, you won't get an error - it just won't bind the parameter - ie as described in the question (+title).

Comment: The ajax is reaching the controller method, the parameter is just NULL. Also tried using querystring to pass the parameters but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a GET verb, it'll be easiest to pass this in as a querystring value. This also conforms better with a [RESTful](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) design.

For example replace `@Url.Action("Nodes","Competence")`

with

`@Url.Action("Nodes","Competence", new { userId = id });`

Then you can delete the data property. This will append **?userId=valueOfId** into your url and then it should be mapped correctly to your action with the `userId` correctly populated.

**Update**

As @freedomn-m stated:

> This will generate the url when the view is built server-side. If the
>   parameters never change, then fine - but it's relatively unlikely that
>   the parameters won't change, in which case you should add the url
>   parameters at runtime if you want them on querystring.

This is completely accurate. Without knowing your exact implementation I can only make assumptions. But technically you could wrap your ajax call in a function and then you could either pass in the `userId` and generate the url within that function or pass in the url, performing the url generation outside of the function.

This would mean that you only need one function that performs the ajax request and you can have another function that gets the `userId` (and possibly generates the url) and then passes that into the ajax function. How you store the `userId` is entirely up to you, but one thing I would suggest is investigating [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) which is a fairly well defined way for storing data on html elements.

Comment: This will generate the url when the view is built server-side.  If the parameters never change, then fine - but it's relatively unlikely that the parameters won't change, in which case you should add the url parameters at runtime if you want them on querystring.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @freedomn-m. I simply took the example and aimed to get it working. I'll add some further information based on your comment. Thanks

Comment: How do I access the paramter? This way: HttpContext.Request.Params.Get("userId")?

Answer (score 0):

Since your server may not expecting a request with JSON content, try removing the **contentType** parameter on your ajax call. Its default value is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" and is fine for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's type should be "POST"

```
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Nodes","Competence")',
    data: { userId: "Test" },
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why?

Comment: Because you are posting some data. That is why will need request type post, If you just append user id into the url then just GET will work.